# How to configure MassTransit with Autofac Module?

Tags: autofac, masstransit, autofac-module

I'm trying to setup MassTransit with Autofac (latest NuGet packages) but it seems that consumers cannot be registered at the `ContainerBuilder` level.
Has anyone managed to use MassTransit with Autofac, especially with modules?

In the sample below, the DoSomethingConsumer cannot be resolved, unless I uncomment the `x.AddConsumer` line and comment the registration on the builder.

```cs
           builder.RegisterType<BusControlHostedService>().As<IHostedService>();
            builder.RegisterType<DoSomethingConsumer>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();

            builder.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                //x.AddConsumer<DoSomethingConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(componentContext => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("host", "vhost", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("user");
                        h.Password("password");
                    });

                    cfg.UseExtensionsLogging(componentContext.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>());

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(componentContext);

                }));

                x.AddRequestClient<DoSomethingRequest>();
            });
```

The documentation at https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/autofac.html seems to be wrong. There is no `.AddConsumer` extension method on the builder.

I'm looking to register consumers from modules and be able to configure endpoints by convention (as in the sample above) or using `.RegisterEndpoint`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of MassTransit? The documentation is correct, and you can see the unit tests for the container as well: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/Autofac_Tests/Autofac_Consumer.cs#L32

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, as mentioned, I'm using the lastest version of MassTransit.
In the link you posted the consumer is not added to the ContainerBuilder (to `builder` ) but inside the configuration action for MassTransit, which is not what I need.
If you look at the https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/autofac.html#using-a-module documentation, it shows how to do this via modules, which is what I need, but that documentation is either wrong or out of date since the methods used do not  exist. Also seems there is some Ninject or Structuremap config in there too.

Comment: The registrar for autofac just uses `builder.RegisterType<T>()`, then you could ask the container for all types which implement `IConsumer` and add them to the registration in the `AddMassTransit` section, similar to how they're added by namespace.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I agree that there are workarounds but I want to do this the clean Autofac way. It seems there is stuff built-in the API for it but I'm not sure how to get it set up.

Comment: I am on a project trying to use Autofac modeuls with MassTransit as well and the module we have setup, which follows the documentation posted above, does not register when injected into a service. Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that ASP.NET Core doesn't request controllers from DI container (IServiceProvider)- it asks for their ctor params instead. So Autofac doesn't see the controllers. You can use `AddControllersAsServices()`, but that will work only for controllers registered before this call. So you need to first register the controllers, then call `AddControllersAsServices()` and it should help